# nodejs - mongodb - how to remove a record

Tags: mongodb, node.js

This is the data

```
{
    "username": "runrun",
    "channel": "all",
    "expire": NumberLong("1308183908743"),
    "_id": ObjectId("4df93f54e07324af47000001")
}
```

This is the code I used to use to remove a record

```
db.collection('seesion',function(err, collection){
    collection.remove({
        "expire": {"$lte": Date.now()}
    },function(err, removed){
        console.log(removed);
    });
});
```

I want to delete the session which has been expired. Problem is, the code doesn't work, maybe there is something to do with numberLong ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled "session" (as "*seesion*").

Comment: Jesus I got the collection name misspelled, that's the reason why ;). And My code works, you just put it inside db.open(function(){})

Comment: Right, I got the code working after all but then realized the typo.  Happens to the best of us =)

Comment: @angry_kiwi Are you using mongoose for this purpose ?

Comment: @SandipSubedi yes